# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application Console Logs Publish to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, .net-6.0

I have deployed a .net 6 application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Windows server). Application has been configured to write application level logs to the console. At the moment, these logs are not published to a CloudWatch by default.

Is there a way that, these console logs can be publised to a Cloudwatch log group? For ex, When using Lambdas, they automatically send console logs to a Cloudwatch stream by default. Something similar would be ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this

To stream instance logs to CloudWatch Logs

- Open the Elastic Beanstalk console, and in the Regions list, select your AWS Region.
- In the navigation pane, choose Environments, and then choose the name of your environment from the list.
- In the navigation pane, choose Configuration.
- In the Software configuration category, choose Edit.
- Under Instance log streaming to CloudWatch Logs:
  Enable Log streaming.
- Set Retention to the number of days to save the logs.
  Select the Lifecycle setting that determines whether the logs are saved after the environment is terminated.
  Choose Apply.
- After you enable log streaming, you can return to the Software configuration category or page and find the Log Groups link. Click this link to see your logs in the CloudWatch console.

Note :- before enabling, you should have proper [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html#AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.prereqs) for cloudwatch agent.

Update ( based on comments )

- .net on Linux supports application, for windows a user need to implement custom solution

> /var/log/eb-engine.log,/var/log/eb-hooks.log,/var/log/web.stdout.log,/var/log/nginx/access.log,/var/log/nginx/error.log

This is an alternate way, https://aws.plainenglish.io/how-to-setup-aws-elasticbeanstalk-to-stream-your-custom-application-logs-to-cloudwatch-d5c877eaa242

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already done this. After setting this up it has created some log groups (IIS-Log, BEDeploy-Log, EBHook.log). But none of them have the application logs that I'm writing to the console. Also, I had followed that link too. I presume, as per it, logs need to be in log files in order to push them to cloud watch.
I'm just thinking to add a serilog-cloudwatch-sink, if console logs can't be automatically published to cloud watch.

Comment: Unfortunately only these three files will be pushed by default You would need to setup custom logs and custom logs configuration or if you use .NET on linux, you can get instance logs + application logs

Comment: Thank Jatin. Yeah I added a separate AWS Cloudfront Sink (I'm using serilog) to tackle this. But good to know that .net + linux handles it out of the box. Will try that as well later on.

Comment: if you dont mind, shall I update my answer so that it helps other in the future

Comment: Of course yes, please do that.

Comment: Updated feel free to accept if it solves your purpose